# How to Add Gmail To Windows 8 Phone?

Tags: gmail, windows-phone-8

I am trying to setup my Moms new windows 8 phone but when I try to add gmail to it I get an error saying I have to enable  Google sync but I am not seeing it in gmail.

Where is it?

Comment: You won't be able to Google retired the product that you require.

Comment: Ask here. They will know. but provide some error code if available http://forums.wpcentral.com/